# How to build an executable file cross platform from linux to windows?

Tags: c, linux, gtk, cross-platform, gtk3

I wrote a GTK3+ project in c , and i am trying to build it so i can make it into a executable file for windows , and i have no idea on how to do it , i saw some articles about building .exe files using MingW so i tried it as such :
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -g -o test PROJECT_INTERFACE.c PROJECT.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`

but i get this error message :

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgay9.png)

can someone help me with building this project for end-user?

Comment: You probably get the errors because you use the host Glib and Gtk+ libraries, not libraries for windows.

Comment: how can i resolve the issue ? do you have an idea?

Comment: Did you had a look at: https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows